# While sending FCM Messages to firebase getting error System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

We are using FCM.Net project to send FCM messages to firebase.
The Google.Apis.dll version is 1.40.0.0.
We are using same ApiKey to send messages our messages.

If we send around around 100K messages to firebase, only 25K get a success.

The rest fail with exception:

While Sending to firebase:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBeginMultipleSend(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers, SocketFlags socketFlags, OverlappedAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginMultipleSend(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginMultipleWrite(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

While Receiving response:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

We are using below code snippet to send the FCM messages and log the responses.:

```
            try
            {
                object customData = new { Email = Email, AccountNum = AccountNum, Badge = 0 };

                using (var sender = new Sender(fireBaseServerKey))
                {
                    var message = new Message
                    {
                        RegistrationIds = new List<string> { FCMToken },
                        Notification = new Notification
                        {
                            Title = Convert.ToString(FCMTitle),
                            Body = Convert.ToString(FCMMessage),
                            Badge = "0"
                        },
                        Data = customData,
                    };

                    uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    ResponseContent result = null;
                    try
                    {
                        if (FCMToken != "" || FCMToken != null || FCMToken != string.Empty)
                        {
                            Log.Info($"Sending To Firebase Cloud Messaging - token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId} | count: {counter}");
                            
                            result = await sender.SendAsync(message);
                            
                            Log.Info($"Sent To Firebase Cloud Messaging - token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId} | count: {counter}");

                            if (result != null && result.MessageResponse != null && result.MessageResponse.Success == 1)
                            {
                                Log.Info($"Success Send To Firebase Cloud Messaging - token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId};

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (result != null && result.MessageResponse != null && result.MessageResponse.Results[0] != null)
                                {
                                    Log.Warn($"Fail Send To Firebase Cloud Messaging - Message: {result.MessageResponse.Results[0].Error} , token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId}");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.Warn($"Fail Send To Firebase Cloud Messaging - token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId}");
                                }

                                isSentSuccess = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            Log.Warn($"FCM Token is Blank - token: {FCMToken}, Email: {Email} , DeviceId: {DeviceId}, UniqueId: {uniqueId}");
                    }
                    catch (
                    Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error($"Firebase Cloud Messaging - SendAsync - Failed with token: {FCMToken}, UniqueId: {uniqueId}");
                        Log.Error(ex.Message);
                        Log.Error(Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Send To Firebase Cloud Messaging Failed with token: {FCMToken}, UniqueId: {uniqueId}");
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
                Log.Error(Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException));
            }
```

Would appreciate your inputs in resolving this issue.